# Related to Kendo Scheduler?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I am using kendo scheduler in MVC and when i tried to add custom button in it, that successfully working but when i resize window it showed me multiple times.

I attached screenshot of my page...here button is shown multiple times..so what is the solution to this to resolve.

here, is my code for scheduler.

```
<script id="groupHeaderTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        <input class="dropdowntree" />
    </div>
</script>
<div id="scheduler">

        @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<BusSchedulingSystem.Web.ViewModels.SchedulerViewModel>()
                    .Name("scheduler")
                    .Date(DateTime.Now)
                    .StartTime(new DateTime(2018, 1, 1, 6, 00, 00))
                    .Views(views =>
                    {
                        views.TimelineMonthView(e => e.EventHeight(50));
                    })

                      .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
                    //.DataSource(d => d

                    //.Read(read => read.Action("", ""))
                    // )
                    //.GroupHeaderTemplate("#= BindDropDownTree(data)#")
                    .GroupHeaderTemplateId("groupHeaderTemplate")
                    .Group(group => group.Resources("Company").Orientation(SchedulerGroupOrientation.Vertical))
                     .Events(events => events.DataBound("onLoad"))

                     .Resources(resource =>
                     {
                         resource.Add(m => m.Company.Id)
                             .Title("Company")
                             .Name("Company")
                             .DataTextField("Name")
                             .DataSource(ds => ds
                                 .Custom()
                                 .Transport(transport => transport.Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Scheduler")))
                                 .Schema(schema => schema
                                     .Data("Data")
                                     .Total("Total")
                                 )
                             );


                     })


        )
    </div>
```

and my onload function is :

```
<script>
    function onLoad(e) {
        debugger
        $('.k-nav-current').hide();
        var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
        var btn = $("<button class='k-button k-my-button'>Add new tour</button>")
        $('#scheduler').find('.k-scheduler-toolbar').append(btn);
         btn.click(function () {
         document.location = '@Url.Action("AddTour", "Tour")'
        });

          //var checkbox = $('<input checked type="checkbox" value="1">');
          //$('#scheduler').find('.k-scheduler-toolbar').append(checkbox);
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Obviously my colleague had the same issue once. This is what I found in our repository:

```cs
var buttonSet = 0;
function addCreateButtonToAgendaView() {
    if (buttonSet === 0) {
        buttonSet = 1;

        var button = $("<a class='k-button k-my-button'>@Resources.BtnNewTask</a>");
        $(getScheduledTasksGrid().toolbar).append(button);
        button.click(function () { $("#scheduler").getKendoScheduler().addEvent(); });
    }
}
```

So you have to set a marker if you've already added the button or not.

(In my original answer, I've accidentally looked into the TreeList instead of the Scheduler. Sorry.)

Comment: Hi, i followed your link but nothing support not even create , or template in scheduler except PDF